# python , launch an external program with ulimit

Tags: python, ulimit

I need to launch an external program from my python script. 
This program crashes, so I need to get a core dump from it.

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the python [resource](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/resource.html?highlight=resource#module-resource) module. It will let you set the size of core files, etc., just like the ulimit command. Specifically, you want to do something like

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE, <size>)
```

before launching your target program.

My guess at usage (I haven't done this myself) is:

```
import resource
import subprocess

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE, 
                   (resource.RLIM_INFINITY,
                    resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
command = 'command line to be launched'
subprocess.call(command)
# os.system(command) would work, but os.system has been deprecated
# in favor of the subprocess module
```

---

Comment: resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE, resource.RLIM_INFINITY)
    os.system( launch_str) ?

Comment: Yes, try that and let me know if that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Actually, setrlimit() requires a tuple for the limits argument. See the example I've added to my answer.

Comment: i got this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLIMIT_INFINITY'

Comment: Oh, sorry. Looking at the reference more closely, it's RLIM_INFINITY (not RLIMIT_...). I've corrected the example.